# Tossing Dice repeatedly, probability that 2nd trial had more tosses than 1st one

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

John repeatedly tosses a die until a six occurs for the first time. Alice then repeats the experiment. What is the probability that Alice made more tosses
than John?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Outline:** Let's first find the probability that Alice and John have **the same** number of tosses. They can either each get their first $6$ on their first toss, or they can each get their first $6$ on their second toss, or each on their third toss, and so on.

The probability it occurs in  the first round is $\frac{1}{6^2}$. The probability it occurs in the second is $\frac{1}{6^2}\frac{5^2}{6^2}$. The probability it occurs in the third is $\frac{1}{6^2}\frac{5^3}{6^3}$. And so on. This is an infinite geometric progression. Calculate the sum, and call it $p$.

Let $a$ be the probability Alice made more tosses. Then $2a+p=1$.  For by symmetry either John made fewer tosses, or Alice made fewer tosses (probabilities equal by symmetry) or there was a tie.

**Added:** The infinite geometric sequence
$$\sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{6^2}\left(\frac{5^2}{6^2}\right)^n$$
has sum $\frac{1}{6^2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{25}{36}}$, which simplifies to $\frac{1}{11}$.

It follows that the probability Alice makes more tosses than John is $\frac{5}{11}$.

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot of sense! So putting the geometric sequence formula for $p$ using $n$ as the number of tosses until a 6 occurs, it should give the result, right?

Comment: The infinite geometric sequence I referred to has sum $\frac{1}{36}\frac{1}{1-\frac{25}{36}}=\frac{1}{11}$. Thus $a=\frac{5}{11}$.